# Xcode 6: How to Disable Optimisation (Swift)

Tags: debugging, swift, xcode6.1

Breakpoints are not being triggered during debugging. I discovered it's because of optimised code.

How can you disable optimisation?
I've walked through every toolbar and the closest option that I could find is `Product => Perform Action => Generate Optimisation Profile`.
This does not work as I am debugging in the simulator, says Xcode.

Is it possible to disable code optimisation in Xcode 6.1 using the simulator and writing in Swift, and if so, how would I go about that?

**SOLUTION:**

1. Click your project name in the project navigator in the left pane under the folder icon.
2. Click 'Build Settings' on the top menu.
3. Scroll down to 'Apple LLVM 6.0 - Code Generation'
4. Under 'Optimization Level' Select 'None [-O0]'

My problem was finding the build settings menu in the first place.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Xcode, look under 'Build Settings' for your target, scroll to 'Swift Compiler - Code Generation' and then 'Optimization Level'.  Ensure that 'None' is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had trouble finding the build settings page.

Comment: I have optimization disabled but my debug steps are still messed. Any other place to look for? BTW this project has those Other Swift Flags `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(COMMON_SWIFT_FLAGS) -DDEBUG -D IOS_EXPOSURE_BUGGED`

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as @Rivera

Answer (score 0):

Set the optimization level to None for Debug.

[image]