# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Crash In Swift For locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

Tags: ios, swift, gps, mapkit, core-location

I am working on GPS functionality.

I have deferred updates setup and I am processing events inside of the appropriate GPS delegate

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

Ive encountered a problem when I try to save routes to a member variable `_userRoutes` which is basically a list the routes the user has taken. `_userRoutes` is valid and declared and works fine by the time this code is called (100%).

In the above callback I have this code:

```
            var route:Route!
            if (self._userRoutes.last?.routeType == self._currentActivityType)
            {
                route = self._userRoutes.last
                route.locations = route.locations + points
                route.locationCoordinates = route.locationCoordinates + points2D
            } else
            {
                // Its a new route so create it
                route = Route()
                route.locations = points
                route.routeType = routeType
                route.startingCoordinate = points2D.first!
                route.startingLocation = points.first!
            }
```

However this code crashes on

```
            if (self._userRoutes.last?.routeType == self._currentActivityType)
```

with a

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

I've even tried printing out all the variables and they all print out just fine AND then it goes back and crashes still.

As you can see below, it prints all 3 prints and then  goes BACK 2 lines to throw the crashing error?!

[image]

So I'm wondering what the issue could be and if you have any ideas I'm all ears! To be clear I'd like to not get the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when its looking up the previous user routes.

*UPDATE*

To be more explicit about checking if user routes is nil (and it crashes) and as you can see it printed the "HERE" only once but it did go back in the stack to crash.[image]

However if I put return statements in there (naturally) the app doesnt crash.

So what I can conclude is that the error is caused by trying to unwrap a nil but there is a source mapping issue where the crash in this case is occuring.

*UPDATE 2*

This is a printout for all the variables at play

```
User Routes: [] //_userRoutes
User Route Count: 0 // _userRoutes.count
User Route last: nil // _userRoutes.last
User Route last type: nil // _userRoutes.last?.routeType
```

*Update 3*

I just started getting this message before the (lldb)

> AppName was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly;
>   variables may not be available.

Comment: You can see that `_userRoutes.last` is nil - This is going to cause you a problem when you unwrap it in the if statement.

Comment: But I have the ? being used, Im not forcing an unwrap

Comment: You are using optional chaining, so you don't get an exception for 'unexpected nil', but you still get a problem when you try and use the nil value.  You should ensure that `self._userRoutes.last?.routeType` isn't nil before you go any further

Comment: I think your assessment is correct but it was obscured by the compiler, I think it incorrectly displayed the logs because it does look like it crashes and go back in the stack with the error. Otherwise "HERE" should appear before the (lldb)

Comment: I also get a crash if I do `if(_userRoutes.last == nil)` and _userRoutes is initialized before this class does anything, its just an array `[]`

Comment: can you just print out the value of _userRoutes and maybe show some of the code that sets it's value?  it really seems like it is nil and crashes when you try to call last on it.

Comment: Yes it prints out as what I initialized it as `[]`. Also note, it will crash if I try and check `_userRoutes.count`. So weird....

Comment: It seems to be the mapping error, if I run `if(_userRoutes.count == 0)` and then have logic later that access checks `if(_userRoutes.last?.routeType)` it goes BACK to the `if(_userRoutes.count == 0) `and crashes!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**

There was a variable much farther down in my code that was nil. Unwrapping THAT variable caused the crash. The compiler was flagging the wrong line which leads to a whole host of confusion.

For full diagnosis look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659053/3324388

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused because you are getting multiple calls to locationManager:manager:didUpdateLocations.  The first time it's called _userRoutes is not nil, but _userRoutes.last is, which is what is printed as nil.  I don't think anything is "going back",  I think a second call is happening, and in that case _userRoutes is nil and causes the crash when you try to call _userRoutes.last.

Print out _userRoutes to confirm this, if not please post more code that shows how _userRoutes is being set.

Comment: Yes I appologize for not making it clearer but I have a print statement ("HERE") before this is run. If it wasnt going backwards and crashing on the second time, it would have fired "HERE" before the crash (which it doesn't).