# Swift: removing an object from NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, swift, nsorderedset

[image]I found that a workaround to remove an object from NSOrderedSet is to remove it from its mutable copy. After fixing XCode's warnings that's the code I have:

```
let tempSet: NSMutableOrderedSet? = playset!.musicItems!.mutableCopy as? NSMutableOrderedSet
        tempSet!.remove(musicItem)
        playset!.musicItems = tempSet
```

But it gives me an error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure tempSet has the musicItem? Check with breakpoints or put an if statement before tempset

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a Swift `Set`?

Comment: Not related but consider to use less question and exclamation marks. Not everything is supposed to be optional. @JAL Swift lacks a native ordered set type.

Comment: @vadian Ah missed that detail.  Likely a dupe of this: [Diagnosing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Swift standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24189738/2415822)

Comment: the issue is that I don't know the type to use for mutableCopy (how to convert), I attached screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mutableCopy` is a method, it must be called as a method, add `()` after it:

```
playset!.musicItems!.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableOrderedSet
```

You are currently trying to cast the method `() -> Any?` itself to an `NSMutableOrderedSet`, not the result of calling that method. Hence the warning.

The cast will never succeed and `tempSet` will always stay `nil`, crashing on the next `!`.